# Increase user (Auth) session in CakePHP

Tags: session, cakephp, authentication

I'm handling the authentication for my with Auth CakePHP. The user session is very low, thus the user logs out quickly after being idle for about 30 mins. This is what I did which doesn't really work:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
  'defaults' => 'php',
  'timeout' => 259200, // 72 hours 
  'cookieTimeout' => 259200 // 72 hours 
  )
);
```

FYI:

```
Configure::write('debug', 2);
```

Is there anything else I should do?

Comment: That looks good. Maybe your PHP settings don't allow the overwriting? You can probably check your ini settings here.

Comment: What's the setting that I need to check in ini?also, do you prefer php or cake of defaults in session?